# Traffic monitoring with SNMP

Tags: snmp, openwrt

I am trying to get bandwidth value of Wan interface in Open-Wrt router (WRT54GL) using

```
OID: 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.4
```

But I keep getting value around 4174517174

I was doing some calculations and it does not make any sense:

4174517174 / 8 / 1024 /1024 = 497 MB/s

Does this value contains more info like time or something or my OID is incorrect ?

Answer (score 1):

I have got the answer. Its the whole traffic which has passed trow this interface. To get the bandwidth you need to get the difference between two past values...

Comment: Yes, _and_ divide by the time difference, in seconds, between those two points.  Essentially, the two points form a line, and the slope of that line is your average bandwidth (in bytes per second); the simple distance between the two points is the _volume_ of traffic (in bytes) over that time period.